# How to interpolate missing years within pd.groupby()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by, interpolation

**Problem:**

I have a dataframe that contains entries with 5 year time intervals. I need to group entries by 'id' columns and interpolate values between the first and last item in the group. I understand that it has to be some combination of groupby(), set_index() and interpolate() but I am unable to make it work for the whole input dataframe.

Sample df:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'id': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b'],
    'year': [2005, 2005, 2010, 2010],
    'val': [0, 0, 100, 100],
    
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

example input df:

```
_    id  year  val
0     a  2005    0
1     a  2010  100
2     b  2005    0
3     b  2010  100
```

expected output df:

```
_     id  year  val type
0      a  2005    0 original
1      a  2006   20 interpolated
2      a  2007   40 interpolated
3      a  2008   60 interpolated
4      a  2009   80 interpolated
5      a  2010  100 original
6      b  2005    0 original
7      b  2006   20 interpolated
8      b  2007   40 interpolated
9      b  2008   60 interpolated
10     b  2009   80 interpolated
11     b  2010  100 original
```

'type' is not necessary its just for illustration purposes.

**Question:**

How can I add missing years to the groupby() view and interpolate() their corresponding values?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a temporary reshaping with [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html)+[`interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) to add the missing years:

```
out = (df
   .pivot(index='year', columns='id', values='val')
   .reindex(range(df['year'].min(), df['year'].max()+1))
   .interpolate('index')
   .unstack(-1).reset_index(name='val')
)
```

Output:

```
   id  year    val
0   a  2005    0.0
1   a  2006   20.0
2   a  2007   40.0
3   a  2008   60.0
4   a  2009   80.0
5   a  2010  100.0
6   b  2005    0.0
7   b  2006   20.0
8   b  2007   40.0
9   b  2008   60.0
10  b  2009   80.0
11  b  2010  100.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In your answer, it seems that the same max year is applied to every group.  I found that jezrael's answer is more general and covers some additional edge cases. I really appreciate your input.

Comment: @Geom yes the same range is applied to every group, I assumed this was the case from your example ;)

Comment: I just tested both solutions and yours is approx 4 times faster. Also, your solution keeps the year column more consistent. Meaning that every 'id' will have a corresponding 'year' even if 'val' for that year is Nan. I am going to accept this! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solution for create years by minimal and maximal years for each group independently:

First create missing values by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) per groups by minimal and maximal values and then interpolate by [`Series.interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html), last identify values from original DataFrame to new column:

```
df = (df.set_index('year')
        .groupby('id')['val']
        .apply(lambda x: x.reindex(range(x.index.min(), x.index.max() + 1)).interpolate())
        .reset_index()
        .merge(df, how='left', indicator=True)
        .assign(type = lambda x: np.where(x.pop('_merge').eq('both'),
                                          'original',
                                          'interpolated')))
print (df)
   id  year    val          type
0   a  2005    0.0      original
1   a  2006   20.0  interpolated
2   a  2007   40.0  interpolated
3   a  2008   60.0  interpolated
4   a  2009   80.0  interpolated
5   a  2010  100.0      original
6   b  2005    0.0      original
7   b  2006   20.0  interpolated
8   b  2007   40.0  interpolated
9   b  2008   60.0  interpolated
10  b  2009   80.0  interpolated
11  b  2010  100.0      original
```

Comment: Worked like charm and covered some edge cases too! Is there anything you would recommend for speeding up this operation?